# Filter with MVC View for IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 there is a need to list a group of clients. I achieved this by creating 2 model ClientList and Client model. I made ClientList class as serializable. Now there is a need to apply filter condition for this model with various parameters. How to achieve this ? Here is my model.

```
public class Client : Paging
{
    public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ClientList : Paging
{
    private Client _client;
    public Client Client
    {
        get { return _client; }
        set { _client = value;  }
    }
}
```

In Data Access, am using this

```
while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var rCompanyName = reader.GetOrdinal("CompanyName");
                        var rFirstName = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstName");
                        var rLastName = reader.GetOrdinal("LastName");

                        var resultClientList = new Client
                                                   {
                                                       CompanyName = Convert.IsDBNull(rCompanyName) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(rCompanyName),
                                                       FirstName = Convert.IsDBNull(rFirstName) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(rFirstName),
                                                       LastName = Convert.IsDBNull(rLastName) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(rLastName)

                                                   };
                        var clients = new ClientList();
                        admin.Client = resultClientList;
                        result.Data.Add(clients);
                    }
```

In view,

```
@model IEnumerable<Midlab.FreightOnce.BusinessObjects.ClientList
@*i need filter condition here*@
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
--rendering list here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach for a beginner I will suggest is, to make two different methods in controller, and two views associated with these controllers. First controller function will be a get function and the view associated with this will open filter lists, user will select the filter criteria and submit it, the second controller function which is a post function will receive the request, fetch records based on filter criteria and returns the response in IEnumerable list to the second view. The Other approach is to use JQuery.ajax calls.

Comment: hi, thanks. The exact requirement must be in the same view, filter conditions on the top and the filtered list at the bottom. Can you pls elaborate your answer for me to understand ?